# House Hold Income report - java

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program that works with an external file. The program has to:
Write a program to read the survey results into three arrays, echo print the data and perform and output the following analyses:

1. Count the number of households included in the survey and print a three-column table displaying the data read in (assume no more than 25 households)
2. Calculate the average household income, and list the identification number and income of each household that exceeds the average.
3. Determine the percentage of households having incomes below the poverty level.  The poverty level income may be computed using the formula:  p= $3750.00 + $750.00 * (m-2) where m is the number of members of each household.

This is what i have so far but it does not seem like it is working (I have to have to classes):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner sf = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("survey2.dat"));

        String[] filePaths = { "D:/survey2.dat" };
        SurveyCollection surveys = new SurveyCollection();
        Runner runner = new Runner();
        runner.load(filePaths, surveys);
        runner.printHouseholdIncomeExceedingAverage(surveys);
        runner.printouseholdBelowPoverty(surveys);
        //print(surveys);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Runner
{
   public static void load(String[] filePaths, SurveyCollection surveys)throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.length; i++) {
      Scanner fileIn = null;
      try {
        fileIn = new Scanner(new FileReader(filePaths[i]));
        while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
          String line = fileIn.nextLine();
          surveys.setSurvey(line);
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      } /*finally {
        fileIn.close();
      }*/
    }
  }

  public static void printHouseholdIncomeExceedingAverage(
      SurveyCollection surveys) {
    int size = surveys.getNumberOfHousehold();
    double average = surveys.getAverageIncome();
    String message = "Households with income exceeding an average income of %,.2f%n";
    System.out.printf(message, average);
    System.out.println("Id   Income Member");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if (surveys.getIncomeByIdx(i) > average) {
        System.out.println(surveys.formattedString(i));
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * design for debug
   * @param surveys
   */
  private static void print(SurveyCollection surveys) {
    int size = surveys.getNumberOfHousehold();
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      System.out.println(surveys.formattedString(i));
    }
  }

  public static void printouseholdBelowPoverty(SurveyCollection surveys) {
    int size = surveys.getNumberOfHousehold();
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if (surveys.isInPoverty(i)) {
        System.out.println(surveys.formattedString(i));
        count++;
      }
    }
    String message = "Percent of households below poverty level = %f%n";
    System.out.printf(message, ((double) count / (double) size));
  }
}

class SurveyCollection {
  final int MAX = 30;
  private int idx = 0;
  private int sumOfIncome = 0;
  private String[] surveyIds = new String[MAX];
  private int[] incomes = new int[MAX];
  private int[] members = new int[MAX];

  public void setSurvey(String value) {
    if (idx < MAX) {
      String[] fields = value.split(" ");
      surveyIds[idx] = fields[0];
      incomes[idx] = Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
      members[idx] = Integer.parseInt(fields[2]);
      sumOfIncome += incomes[idx];
      idx++;
    }
  }

  public int getNumberOfHousehold() {
    return this.idx;
  }

  public double getAverageIncome() {
    return (double) sumOfIncome / getNumberOfHousehold();
  }

  public int getIncomeByIdx(int idx) {
    return incomes[idx];
  }

  public String formattedString(int idx) {
    String style = "%s %d %d";
    return String.format(style, this.surveyIds[idx], this.incomes[idx], this.members[idx]);
  }

  public boolean isInPoverty(int idx) {
    boolean result = false;
    int threadhold = (3750 + 750 * members[idx]);
    result = incomes[idx] <= threadhold;
    return result;
  }

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

External File:

```
1041 12180 4
1062 13240 3
1327 19800 2
1483 22458 8
1900 17000 2
2112 18125 7
2345 15623 2
3210 3200 6
3600 6500 5
3601 11970 2
4725 8900 3
6217 10000 2
9280 6200 1
```

Output should be similar to this:

```
id     income    members
1041     12180       4
1062     13240       3
1327     19800       2
1483     22458       8
1900     17000       2
2112     18125       7
2345     15623       2
3210       3200       6
3600       6500       5
3601     11970       2
4725       8900       3
6217     10000       2
9280       6200       1


Households with income exceeding an average income of 12707.4

 id     income    members
1062     13240       3
1327     19800       2
1483     22458       8
1900     17000       2
2112     18125       7
2345     15623       2

Percent of households below poverty level = 0.0769231
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about your problem. What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: Thanks i was trying to do that but i couldn't get it to do so.

Comment: I expect it to print out the id, income and the total members in the external file then find the average income of the households. Then print the house holds that exceed the average income while also including the average of the households who are below the poverty line. However, nothing actually happens.

Comment: Literally nothing happens when you run this? No error message, no output? I don't think that's possible because your `printHouseholdIncomeExceedingAverage` method should always print at least something, even if the collection is empty.

Comment: Without a sample file it would be difficult for others to test this sample, it's not self-contained (http://sscce.org).

Comment: It stops at fillin.close that save java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: @BaileySpell: So when you said "nothing happens" it was in fact incorrect because something *does* happen, namely you get an error message?

Comment: Yes sorry.. It doesn't print anything the error message say  java.lang.NullPointerException: null and its on the line with the finally{ filein.close();

Comment: You need to check if the file is not null before calling close on it

Comment: Should i do that in the finally or put this try, catch, and finally all in the if?

Comment: I voted to close because "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." This question is clearly not the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I get some output when I pass the entire file path to the runner.load method.

```
    String fileName = "survey2.dat";
    String filePaths[] = {"C:\\Users\\Neal\\Desktop\\" + fileName};


        Households with income exceeding an average income of 12,707.38
Id   Income Member
1062 13240 3
1327 19800 2
1483 22458 8
1900 17000 2
2112 18125 7
2345 15623 2

3210 3200 6
3600 6500 5
Percent of households below poverty level = 0.153846
```

Comment: So what did you alter exactly? At least give an explanation instead of just pasting a bunch of code.

Comment: There is nothing in the output.

Comment: the file input operations.  Looking at it right now and there appears to be an issue with the scanner operations.  One possible solution would be to use a different reader like a BufferedReader.

Comment: when you debug this it throws an error at the following line: fileIn = new Scanner(new FileReader(filePaths[i]));  It looks like you're trying to read a directory as a file.  This is what it's trying to scan in: [C:\Users\Neal\Desktop\]